# In c I try to get one student information from a file and try to put that informations into struct but it is not working

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct, file-read

my struct format is like this

```c
struct {
    char student_ID[11];
    char full_name [MAX];
    char program [MAX];
    char year;
    char e_mail [MAX*2];
    char status;
} student_info;
```

And this is my function which tries to get one student information

```c
void scanStudents(FILE *file, student_info *student) {
    char get_line [500];
    fgets(get_line,500,file);

    char *ID = strtok(get_line,";");
    strcpy(student->student_ID, ID);
    char *NAME = strtok(get_line, ";");
    strcpy(student->full_name, NAME);
    char *PROGRAM = strtok(get_line,";");
    strcpy(student->program, PROGRAM);
    char *YEAR = strtok(get_line, ";");
    strcpy(student->year,YEAR);
    char *E_MAIL = strtok(get_line, ";")
    strcpy(student->e_mail,E_MAIL);
    char *STATUS = strtok(get_line,";");
    strcpy(student->status, STATUS);
}
```

I open file in other function and by calling this function in that my aim is try to store student informations in one array which type is student_ınfo. The txt file contains many student information in type of

```
31300000010;DURU  AY;Computer Engineering;2;duru.ay@tedu.edu.tr;
```

Comment: You are using `strtok` incorrectly. To begin parsing a string you pass the string pointer to the function. To continue you pass NULL. Since `year` and `status` are single characters and not arrays you can't use `strcpy` to copy data into them.

Comment: `student_ID` cannot hold a string of length 11. You need to add space for terminating 0 byte. Also you should ensure that the token you copy is not longer than the destination buffer.

Comment: `fgets` stores the `\n` in the buffer. You might want to use delimiters `";\n"` for your last token which is missing in your example, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example including error fixes that @Retired Ninja and @Gerhardh stated.
The file content is:

```
31300000010;DURU AY;Computer Engineering;2;duru.ay@tedu.edu.tr;A
```

Now this one is for storing each field as string. The fixes I made to your code are the following:

- `student_info` declaration and its definition are fixed.
- Add MIN_STRING to comply min String length that is 1 character + 1 NULL termination.
- Change the `year` and `status` fields so that they comply the minimum string space requirements.
- Add some NULL checks, perhaps to avoid corrupted student info.
- Used only one pointer `temp` to hold the pointer address which is returned by `strtok` function.

This sample code is for reference only. So you adapt the idea behind this code to your actual code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Minimum string size must be 2 in order to store 1 character + terminating (NULL or '\0') character
#define MIN_STRING 2
#define MAX (50+1) // 1 character space for the NULL terminator.

struct student_info {
    char student_ID[12];
    char full_name [MAX];
    char program [MAX];
    char year[MIN_STRING];
    char e_mail [MAX];
    char status[MIN_STRING];
};

const char *file_name = "students.txt";

int main(void) {
    
    FILE *file_students = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if(file_students == NULL) {
        printf("The file named %s could not be read\n", file_name);
        return 1; // Return with some failure code
    }
    
    char get_line[500];
    char *temp = NULL;
    struct student_info student;
    
    fgets(get_line, 500, file_students);
    
    temp = strtok(get_line,";");
    strcpy(student.student_ID, temp);
    // After the first invocation of strtok you must pust NULL
    temp = strtok(NULL, ";");
    // strtok returns NULL if there are not any tokens left
    if(temp == NULL) {
        puts("Student ID NULL");
        return 1;
    }
    strcpy(student.full_name, temp);
    temp = strtok(NULL,";");
    if(temp == NULL) {
        puts("Name NULL");
        return 1;
    }
    strcpy(student.program, temp);
    temp = strtok(NULL, ";");
    if(temp == NULL) {
        puts("Program NULL");
        return 1;
    }
    strcpy(student.year,temp);
    temp = strtok(NULL, ";");
    if(temp == NULL) {
        puts("Year NULL");
        return 1;
    }
    strcpy(student.e_mail,temp);
    temp = strtok(NULL,";");
    if(temp == NULL) {
        puts("E-mail NULL");
        return 1;
    }
    strcpy(student.status, temp);
    
    puts("Sample student information");
    printf(
        "ID: %s\nFull name: %s\nProgram: %s\nYear: %s\nE-mail: %s\nStatus: %s\n",
        student.student_ID, student.full_name, student.program, student.year,
        student.e_mail, student.status
           );
    
    // Close the file
    fclose(file_students);
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output of the sample code:

```
Sample student information
ID: 31300000010
Full name: DURU AY
Program: Computer Engineering
Year: 2
E-mail: duru.ay@tedu.edu.tr
Status: A
```